# Cocoa REAL SLOW NSTextView. Is there a better way to append text to the contents of NSTextView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I am very new to Cocoa and this is probably a complete newb question. I am frustrated to death however.

I have an extremely simple Cocoa app (called "lines") to test sending 1000 lines of text to a text view.

I started in Xcode 4 with "new Cocoa project" with all the defaults. This gives a blank window object upon which I can drag IB UI elements.

The UI I then constructed consists of a Text View and a button on the window of a NIB file. I am using Xcode 4 to drag those two elements to the .h file. The text view is connected to `outView` and the "1000" button is connected to `one_thousand_button` method.

[image: The UI]

Clicking the button "1000" triggers a loop to print 1,000 lines of text ("line 1\n" "line 2\n" ... "line 1000") to the NSTextView called "outView"

Here is the entire code (other than the .XIB file described):

linesAppDelegate.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface linesAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
@private
    NSWindow *window;
    NSTextView *outView;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSTextView *outView;
- (IBAction)one_thousand_button:(id)sender;

@end
```

linesAppDelegate.m:

```
#import "linesAppDelegate.h"

@implementation linesAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize outView;

- (IBAction)one_thousand_button:(id)sender {
    NSString* oldString;
    NSString* newString;

    for(int i=1; i<=1000; i++){
        oldString = [outView string];
        newString = [oldString stringByAppendingString: 
                     [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Line %i\n",i]];
        [outView setString: newString];    
    }
}
@end
```

This is REALLY SLOW to execute. Perhaps 7 seconds the first time and increasingly slow with each press of "1000". Even has the spinning colorful pizza of death!

I realize that this is probably not the right way to fill a NSTextView with 1,000 lines of text and that the loop that read the contents of the text view and appends that with `stringByAppendingString` method is the bottleneck.

What is the alternative method however?

**Result**

I wrapped this code:

```
    mach_timebase_info_data_t info;
    mach_timebase_info(&info);
    uint64_t start = mach_absolute_time();

// timed code    

    uint64_t duration = mach_absolute_time() - start;
    duration *= info.numer;
    duration /= info.denom;
    duration /= 1000000;

    NSLog(@"timed code took %lld milliseconds!", duration);
```

around the code from [Adam Preble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495065/cocoa-real-slow-nstextview-is-there-a-better-way-to-append-text-to-the-contents/5495287#5495287), my original, and [drewk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495065/cocoa-real-slow-nstextview-is-there-a-better-way-to-append-text-to-the-contents/5495177#5495177):

```
                 Adam Preble  (Adam, base)     drewk    my pitiful code
 1st run:           3ms          269ms         260ms      1,950ms
 2nd run            3ms          269ms         250ms      2,332ms
 3rd run:           2ms          270ms         260ms      2,880ms
```

The first run adds 1,000 lines; 2nd run adds another 1,000 lines, etc. (Adam, base) is his code without the `beginEditing` and `endEditing`

It is clear that using `beginEditing` and `endEditing` is WAY faster!

See the Apple documents on [Synchronizing Editing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/TextEditing/Tasks/BatchEditing.html).

Comment: The slowness probably isn't the `NSTextView` itself but rather that you're allocating 2 new strings every time you loop (1 via the `stringWithFormat:` and the other as the result of `stringByAppendingString:`) and then changing the string of the textView every iteration.  @drewk's answer should really help to speed this up.

Comment: "spinning colorful pizza of death!" 

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Wrap your updates to the text storage in calls to `beginEditing` and `endEditing`.  This causes Cocoa to hold all of its change notifications until you have finished making your changes to the text storage.

```
- (IBAction)oneThousandButton:(id)sender
{
    NSTextStorage *textStorage = [outView textStorage];
    [textStorage beginEditing];
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
    {
        NSString *line = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Line %i\n", i];
        [textStorage replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange([textStorage length], 0)
                                   withString:line];
    }
    [textStorage endEditing];
}
```

On my system the above action runs in about 10ms.  If I comment out the calls to `beginEditing`/`endEditing`, it takes about 470ms.

Comment: Huge speed up -- fantastic answer -- I can load 100,000 lines of  Lorem Ipsum attributed strings almost instantly -- I get the spinning beachball 10,000 without this. Blows a fuse and fails for 1,000,000 lines though...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
- (IBAction)one_thousand_button:(id)sender {

    for(int i=1; i<=1000; i++){      
         [[[outView textStorage] mutableString] appendString: 
                    [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Line %i\n",i]];
    }
}
```

There is an invaluable "quickie" reference to Objective-C [HERE](http://borkware.com/quickies/) with NSTextView covered [HERE.](http://borkware.com/quickies/one?topic=NSTextView)

Best...

Comment: If you add the `beginEditing/endEditing` as in @Adam Preble method, this is just as fast as maybe easier to read...